# Issue in Sorting date in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The date sorting in gridview is not working properly.

Fieldname : Lossdate 
datatype : nvarchar(255)

In sql ,the datatype is nvarchar because the date field also has some formatted string values
(Eg:A90317,A00921 like this)

While retrieving the data from db,am casting the data as date format and binding it in grid.

```
  SELECT name,location,convert(date,lossdate, 101) as LossDate from valuation
```

My expected results would be like this

```
NULL

NULL

NULL

A90118

A90317

A00921 

2004-05-27

2004-10-26

2010-07-14

2010-10-05

2011-04-07
```

`null` should come first,

formatted string date format comes second,

correct date format should come in sorted manner next

In gridview,the lossdate is like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LossDate" HeaderText="Loss Date" SortExpression="LossDate" 
   dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  />
```

Please help me in solving this

Comment: Try to use Order By clause.

Comment: your problem is the dual usage of a field that should be a date, try fixing that first.  Otherwise it is rightly being sorted as a string, where numbers come before letters.  If you don't like that you're going to have to write your own sorting.

Comment: also, unless you're actually storing unicode don't use nvarchar datatype, and size your column more appropriately, from the data you've provided 255 looks to be a bit large.

Comment: order by also not giving the expected result

Comment: But i cannt use date datatype as it has string values.I tried with removing cast in query,sorting is not proper with the string type also.It is not giving expected result

Comment: I agree with BlackICE and if you can not do what he suggested, write CASE statement for expected order after converting it to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Below `Query` if you want to avoid coding in `Front-End`

```
select name,location,Lossdate 
  from (select top (select COUNT(*) 
                      from valuation 
                     where ISDATE(Lossdate) = 0)  name,location,Lossdate  
          from valuation 
         Where ISDATE(Lossdate) = 0 
         order by Lossdate) T1
 union all
select name,location,Lossdate 
  from (select top (select COUNT(*) 
                      from valuation 
                     where ISDATE(Lossdate) <> 0) name,location,Lossdate  
          from valuation 
         Where ISDATE(Lossdate) <> 0 
         order by convert(date,Lossdate, 120)) T2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = table.AsEnumerable()
 .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("LossDate") !=null)
    .ThenByDescending(p => !DateTime.TryParse(p.Field<string>("LossDate"), out dt))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("LossDate"));
var result =temp.AsDataView().ToTable();
```

and set above as DataSource of girdview

Sample :

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("LossDate", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2004, 05, 27));
table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);
table.Rows.Add("A90317");
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2009, 06, 27));
table.Rows.Add("A90118");
table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);
table.Rows.Add("A00921");
table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2005, 06, 27));
DateTime dt;
var temp = table.AsEnumerable()
 .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("LossDate") !=null)
    .ThenByDescending(p => !DateTime.TryParse(p.Field<string>("LossDate"), out dt))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("LossDate"));
var result =temp.AsDataView().ToTable();
```

result :

```
LossDate 
null  
null  
null  
A00921 
A90118 
A90317 
27/05/2004 12:00:00 AM 
27/06/2005 12:00:00 AM 
27/06/2009 12:00:00 AM
```